# File Card Preview not working on Aura App

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have an aura component that uses the file card tag to display a file(contentDocument)

```
<lightning:fileCard fileId='{!v.salesforceFileId}' description='Selected Template'/>
```

This works fine whenever I launch the component from a quick action. But I have another scenario where I need to launch an aura app that wraps this component and here is where the error occurs. I can't see the preview at all, can't even click on it.

This is what I get:

[image]

any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is working according to the documentation [lightning:fileCard](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileCard/documentation). Take a look at "Targets"

> Lightning Experience, Experience Builder Sites, Salesforce Mobile App

It should be mentioned as a target `Standalone Lightning App` in order to have that component working in standalone app.

For example, [lightning:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example) has the following targets:

> Lightning Experience, Experience Builder Sites, Lightning Out /
> Visualforce, Standalone Lightning App

As for now, **Summer '22**, you can't use this component in standalone lightning app, unfortunately.

Comment: Thats correct. Thanks!